# Timepart Constraint Format?

Tags: sas

I have a field in my proc sql statement to extract the time from a datetime field.

```
timepart(submit_time) format time10. as time
```

This returns time perfectly as expected.

18AUG18:11:13:10 returns 11:13:10.

However I need to create a case statement and cannot determine how to format the value properly for the constraint. E.g. When comparing a date I would use > '18AUG2018'd. What would be the equivalent for a timepart?

attempting something like this

```
case when timepart(submit_time) format time10. > 10:00:00 then 1 else 0 end as time_flag
```

sas doesn't like the format in the case statement as well.

Comment: See date and datetime constants in this document and the examples. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lepg/p1ugvn0mocff92n13mw9s56300jv.htm

Comment: Off the topic, you could use boolean expression to make your code clean: `(timepart(submit_time)>'10:00:00't) as time_flag`

Answer (score 3):

Use the letter T for TIME.

```
 case when timepart(submit_time) < '12:00't then 'MORNING'
      else 'AFTERNOON'  end as AM_PM
```

The value in the quotes needs to be something that the TIME informat can read.  Just like the quoted value for a date literal needs to work with the DATE informat.  Use suffix of DT for DATETIME.

```
 where submit_time >= '01JAN2021:00:00'dt
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but i had the format statement in there as well. Removed that and it worked like charm. Much thanks! Happy holidays.

Comment: The format is not part of the TIMEPART() expression. The FORMAT or FORMAT= is for attaching attributes to the variable that is going to be saved.  Other attributes you can attach to a variable are LABEL=, INFORMAT= or LENGTH=.

Comment: Thank you again!